# How to obtain all transactions of customer (python)

Tags: python, braintree

I need to implement a page containing all transactions of a customer.
In the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/reference/response/customer#transactions) it's written that the customer contains `transactions` property, but in the latest version of the api (3.10.0) this is not true. How can I obtain all transaction of the given customer?
I also looked inside the api, in particular I found that in `braintree.Transaction` class there is the method `search`, but in the docs it's not written how to use it.

```
@staticmethod
def search(*query):
    return Configuration.gateway().transaction.search(*query)
```

It this method usable?

Thanks

Comment: lets say i type name = "xyz" . So u want to get all of xyz's transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. Thanks for spotting the error in the docs. If you need more help, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The `customer.transactions` method is a mistake in the Braintree docs. You can [search for transactions using customer id](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/sdk/server/transaction-processing/search#vault-associations):

```
search_results = braintree.Transaction.search(
    braintree.TransactionSearch.customer_id == "the_customer_id"
)
```